# Convert Map Key and values into Dataframe using Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have map object like below, Want to convert these Map into DataFrame using Scala Spark

```
val mapObj = Map(Col1 -> TRL2023112300000, Col2 -> 12213.00)


val rows = mapObj.values.toList

val column = mapObj.keys.toString


val df = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(rows)).toDF(column)

df.show()
```

**Expected Value**

```
+--------------------++--------------------+

|           col1     |     Col2            |

+--------------------++--------------------+

|TRL20231123000000    | 12213.00           |

+--------------------++--------------------+
```

Comment: yes. it was helpful. thank you